# number stored as text conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have conditionally formatted a column of serial numbers to color duplicates.

This column is formatted as text.

Problem: when a serial number is added that is not not alpha numeric is is not recognized as a duplicate. Number stored as text error is preventing duplicate.

Question: how do I get the serial numbers that are not alpha numeric to color when duplicated.

Comment: How is your conditional formatting defined? Can you edit your question and show this?

Comment: Highlight cell rules then duplicate values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's some difference you don't see. You can use the `Exact()` worksheet function in order to check if two cells have an equal value or not.

As far as checking numerical and alphabetical values, this works fine, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: How do I get to where you entered this formula?

Comment: I just entered it in the formula bar.

Comment: found where to enter formula, thank you

below is a screenshot of problem, the pink works fine for alpha numeric.

in yellow I have formula where excel says they match and in green I have where they are both text. the only difference I can see is the error on F75

please see link

Comment: here is the link

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this is my first time here. The duplicates are not exact. First one comes from a SQL report just text, second comes  from scanning a bar code and is a number stored as text.  Can I conditionally format to find these as duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

I found where to enter formula, thank you

below is a screenshot of problem, the pink works fine for alpha numeric.

in yellow I have formula where excel says they match and in green I have where they are both text. the only difference I can see is the error on F75

[image: inline please see link]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please edit your question instead. In top of that, both values are not **exactly** the same (the one is a number and the other is a text, most probably preceded by the invisible apostroph character). Please check this with the `Exact()` function, as shown in my answer.